# Cursor = <custom cursor> does not stick on dialog form

Tags: c#, winforms

The dialog works as a color picker w/ a shot of the entire desktop as it's background and is instantiated from a form.

The dialog's Cursor property is set to a pipette (custom) cursor on load.

The region on the dialog where the parent form appears is set to transparent so current color at pixel location is reflected on the parent form.

On load, however, the cursor momentarily changes to a pipette cursor and then changes back to default, regardless.

I'm not sure what's happening. I already tried setting the pipette cursor again OnMouseHover, OnMouseMove, heck even OnPaint, on the dialog, but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out in the Form load.
It worked for my Custom cursor (Controll for the Cursor was a Button)

```
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(CustomCursorPath);
Controlname.Cursor = new Cursor(ms);
```

Comment: This is what I'm doing already. The problem is, somehow, Cursor property of the dialog reverts to default when the transparent region gets hit and the mouse cursor no longer becomes a pipette when mouse hovers back to the dialog.